# How to improve loops without breaks and ifs

Tags: c

I've started to learn C and I have one doubt. For example, imagine I have a loop like this:

```c
while(*line && flag) {
  do something 1 that changes flag;
  if(!flag) break;

  do something 2 that changes flag;
  if(!flag) break;

  do something 3 that changes flag;
  if(!flag) break;

  do something 4 that changes flag;
  if(!flag) break;

  ...and goes on...
}
```

Well, of course it will only check the condition when all the do something are done so it will only check the last flag's value.

I would like to know if there is anyway it could detect the flag after "do something 1" and stop the cycle without so many breaks and ifs. Just for curiosity and trying to learn how to do good things!

Thank you so much!!

---- Edit ----
Some of you asked to clarify more! So for example, I have a struct and I want to insert the data in it as I receive it.
So imagine I have name, age and address. And I only want to insert if they are valid as per some rules I can create.

So if the name is invalid I don't want even to valid the rest or insert, I want to move on to receive the next data for the next struct. But if the name is valid I want to check if the age is and so on.

Thank you for everyone who tried to help!

Comment: You could do `while(*line && DoSomething1() && DoSomething2() ...) {}`.

Comment: You could make an array of functions and iterate over it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it is very readable over functions.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of *"do something that changes flag;"*. It may be possible to refactor the code to avoid `flag` altogether.

Comment: It is the most readable and correct way. I do not understand your problem.

Comment: You can probably just put `break` in place of `flag = false;`

Comment: In general, the more little flags like that you have, the more confusing and error-prone and hard-to-maintain your code will be.  In general, the biggest need for flags like that is if you subscribe to a programming philosophy that says that using `break` is bad.  If not, then instead of setting a flag that tells you to break, you can just directly do the `break`.  (Having a flag variable, but then calling `break`, seems to me like the worst of both worlds!)

Comment: Your other options are to use "continue" instead of "break", or use deeply-nested ifs. I think your original method is clearest.

Comment: Writing a good loop — with the right entry and exit conditions and [loop invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) and whatnot — is an art.  A good loop clearly expresses its intent and can be clearly seen to meet its requirements.  A bad loop — particularly one littered with extraneous little flag variables that are set in one place and then tested in another — can be even more opaque and unmaintainable than if it was written with a bunch of old-school `goto` statements.

Comment: But like any art form, it's hard to give generic guidance that magically imparts goodness.  It's much easier to suggest good patterns if we have some notion of what specific problem you're trying to solve today.  It's an open question whether the right thing to do with your four somethings is to retain them, or write them more cleanly, or relegate them to subfunctions, or eliminate them entirely, or some other approach.  Depending on your specific problem, vastly different approaches may be preferable in the long run.

Comment: Thank you all!! I've just edited the post

Comment: In response to the edit, this can be done by putting the user input code into a function. The function can `return` early when things go wrong. The return value from the function should indicate whether the function succeeded or failed. When it succeeds, use the data that the user entered. When it fails, display a helpful error message, and call the function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of cleaning up code like this is to flip everything upside down, so to speak.  Instead of a flag saying things aren't okay, use one saying that things are:

```
bool still_okay = true;

while(*line && still_okay) {

    if(still_okay) {
        do something 1 that might change still_okay;
    }

    if(still_okay) {
        do something 2 that might change still_okay;
    }

    if(still_okay) {
        do something 3 that might change still_okay;
    }

    if(still_okay) {
        do something 4 that might change still_okay;
    }

  ...and goes on...
}
```

Comment: Ohhh it makes sense of course!! Thank you so much :) Sorry I cannot vote up your comment yet i tried but it says i dont have the reputation required as I'm a new user. But consider suuuper up